# How to insert multiple values in Charts.js inside one title?

Tags: chart.js

So i made charts js bar chart working, i made it working also as a group bar chart. It goes easy when you need one label ('Date for example'), and then one value for that label inside dataset. But what i need is this:

```
  - On some date label  i need to show 4 bars (apples sold, bananas sold, oranges etc), and 
    then on a second date label i need only 2 bars (bananas and oranges), and when u hover 
    over i need it saying what is what, and what value holds each bar..
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a dataset for each part so one for apples sold, one for oranges sold etc, in the data array you can put the numbers, if nothing is sold that day you can put a `null` value or `0` in there

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["05/05", "06/05", "07/05", "08/05", "09/05", "10/05"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Apples sold',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      },
      {
        label: 'Bananas sold',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'yellow'
      },
      {
        label: 'Oranges sold',
        data: [10, null, null, 0, 6, 2],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```